# How should I disable or change Alt+digit \for switching tabs in gnome terminal?

Tags: emacs, gnome-terminal

I open emacs in gnome terminal 3.6.2 in Ubuntu 14.04. In emacs, I would like to hit `M-[number]`, but that was interpreted as switching tabs in gnome terminal. How can I change or disable the key bindings in gnome terminal? Edit->Keyboard shortcuts doesn't seem editable:

[image]

Comment: Works for me.  Have you tried pressing space, or clicking the highlighted line – followed by a new key combo?

Comment: Doesn't work forme. Yes, I have.   ....

Comment: Odd. I've tried 3.6.2 in both 14.04 and 14.10 (I happen to have both here).  And it works as I would expect it to.  Sounds like you got some gremlins among your gnomes.

Comment: I might be stating the obvious, but this also might be the point the original poster is missing: In the screenshot, you should double click on Alt+3 or press Enter or Space after highlighting the desired line. Then when it says "New accelerator..." press Backspace to remove the current binding.